# Obtener datos (JSON) de un api en Spring Boot

Tags: java

Estoy usando una api donde debo obtener un json que contiene unos datos y un array:
La url es: https://secure.payco.co/restpagos/pse/bancos.json?public_key=mikey y el nombre de mis variables con sus getter y setter son como indica la documentación en https://docs.epayco.co/methods/pse y me gustaría mas obtener los datos en mi clase CPseVO pero no me funciona por el array de Data.

Clase que consume el servicio

```
private static RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
public static void pse() {
        String URL_PSE = "https://secure.payco.co/restpagos/pse/bancos.json?public_key=mikey";

        try {
                        
            ResponseEntity<CPseVO> response = rest.exchange(URL_PSE,HttpMethod.GET, null, CPseVO.class);
            CPseVO psevo = response.getBody();

            System.out.print("El title response: "+psevo.getTitle_response());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("el error de pse: " + e);
        }

    }
```

```
public class CPseVO {
    private boolean success;
    private String title_response, text_response, last_action;
    private String[] data;

    // Los de mas metodos set y get no los pongo por que si funcionan el que 
    // no me sirve el este

    public String[] getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

El error:

```
el error de pse: org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [class com.app.consume.CPseVO] and content type [application/json]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `[Ljava.lang.String;` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `[Ljava.lang.String;` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 140] (through reference chain: com.app.consume.CPseVO["data"])

Sobre esta variable es el error no se si la cree mal:

    public String[] getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
```

Comment: y tu payload cual es?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema esta en el atributo "data" tu clase "CPseVO".
Si te das cuenta el API al que llamas te retorna de este modo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que significa que el campo "data" viaja como un objeto, pero en tu clase "CPseVO" esta como un arreglo de string, lo cual te manda un "JSON parse error".

Para solucionarlo en tu clase "CPseVO" cambia el atributo "*private String[] data*" y ponlo como un objeto *"private Data data"* . Te quedaria del siguiente modo:

```
public class CPseVO {
  private boolean success;
  private String title_response, text_response, last_action;
  private Data data;
  //Getter & Setter ...
}
```

Y en tu clase "Data":

```
public class Data{
   private Integer totalErrores;
   private List<Errores> errores;
   //Getter & Setter
}
```

Como veras se declara un "List de Errores", por lo tanto debes crear una clase "Errores"

```
public class Errores {
   private String codError;
   private String errorMessage;
}
```

Finalmente probamos y vemos la consola:

```
private static RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String URL_PSE = "https://secure.payco.co/restpagos/pse/bancos.json?public_key=mikey";
    ResponseEntity<CPseVO> response = rest.exchange(URL_PSE, HttpMethod.GET, null, CPseVO.class);
    CPseVO psevo = response.getBody();

    System.out.println(psevo.getData());

  }
}
```

Y obtenemos el resultado correctamente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos.